# Let $(X, \mathcal{M})$ be a measurable space and $\mu : \mathcal{M} → [0, \infty]$. Show that $\mu$ is a measure.

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification, measurable-sets

Let $(X, \mathcal{M})$ be a measurable space and $\mu : \mathcal{M} → [0, \infty]$ such that

(a) $µ (A) <\infty$ for some $A \in \mathcal{M}$
(b) $µ(A \cup B) = \mu(A) + \mu(B)$ if $A, B \in \mathcal{M}$ and $A \cap B = \emptyset$, and
(c) $\mu (\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n}) \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_n) $ if $A_n \in \mathcal{M}$ for $n=1,2,3,...$

Show that $\mu$ is a measure.

In my context, we define a measure as follows:

**Definition:**
*A function µ is called a positive measure, defined in a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{M}$ with values in $[0, \infty]$ and which is countably additive. This means that if $\{E_i\}$ is a disjoint countable collection of elements of $\mathcal{M}$, then $\mu (\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} E_{i}) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\mu(E_i)$. 

To avoid trivial cases, we will further assume that $\mu (A) < \infty $ for at least one $A \in \mathcal{M}$*

**My attempt:**

From the definition, it only remains for me to prove that $\mu$ is countably additive. To do this, let $\{A_n\}$ be a disjoint countable collection of elements of $\mathcal{M}$. Then, $$ \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n  \supset \bigcup_{n=1}^{N}A_n$$ And so
$$\mu \left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n \right)  \geq \mu \left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{N}A_n \right) = \sum_{n=1}^{N}\mu(A_n)$$

Since the left side of this inequality is independent of $N$, we have $$\mu \left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n \right)  \geq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(A_n)$$
For part (c) we have the equality.

First of all I want to know if there are any errors in my reasoning and, on the other hand, I don't see where I used the hypothesis of part **(b)** in my proof; This really does have me worried. I appreciate any help you can give me.

Comment: You wrote the inequality $$\mu \left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n \right)  \geq \mu \left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{N}A_n \right) \color{red}{=} \sum_{n=1}^{N}\mu(A_n).$$
To get the equality $\color{red}{=}$ on the right, you did use **(b)**, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have done seems correct. In fact, what you have done shows that given any $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{M}$ and any map $\mu : \mathcal{M} \to [0, \infty]$ with the property **(b)** *alone*, it follows that given a disjoint collection $\{A_i\}_i$, it is the case that $$\sum_{i = 1}^\infty \mu(A_i) \le \mu\left(\bigcup_{i = 1}^\infty A_i\right).$$

(As pointed in the comments, you used **(b)** to conclude that $$\mu \left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{N}A_n \right) \color{red}{=} \sum_{n=1}^{N}\mu(A_n),$$
which really follows by induction and **(b)**.)

Property **(c)** was then just the minimum required for you to conclude equality.

As an exercise, you could try to come up with an example to show that **(c)** is really needed and doesn't just follow from **(b)**.

---

I have ignored **(a)** in the above. Clearly, it is only there to avoid the case that $\mu$ is identically $\infty$, which is what your definition also demands. However, note that it is equivalent to demanding that $\mu(\varnothing) = 0$, assuming either **(b)** or countable additivity. (How?)

Comment: Thank you. Now everything is clear thanks to you.